# SweetAlert2 in while button not working on last row

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, sweetalert2

I have a table generated in while on PHP, There's a delete button that shows Sweetalert to confirm and redirect to PHP. All is working fine, But the last row in table Sweetalert is not showing up.

Here's the code inside while for this button (Not finished yet, just testing):

```
<script>
$('.delmod').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
swal({

        title: 'Jesteś pewien że chcesz usunąć moduł?',
        text: 'Jeżeli są strony przypisane do tego modułu, nie będzie możliwe go usunąć',
        type: 'warning',
        buttonsStyling: false,
        confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-primary',
        cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-light',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Tak, usuń',
        cancelButtonText: "Nie"

    });
});
</script>
            <a href="includes/deleteModule.php?id=<?=$mod['id'];?>" class="delmod"><i class="icon-cross2"></i></a>
```

I have all rows and the button on right side, Sweetalert is called when clicked and this is working fine. But the last record on the table is not working, I tried with other tables, With different records count, Even if I have 2 rows the first one is working and second (last) is not. Sorry for my English and thank for you help (I'm noobie)

Comment: the script needs to be _after_ the html - or wrapped in a document.ready. _BUT_ you shouldn't have this script inside the loop, printed several times. Move it to _after_ the loop.

Comment: yeah! its working now, thank you for your help!

Comment: how i can vote your comment as a solution? Sorry im really noob here, learning all  :D

Comment: @user1595183 You can't. Jeff should post an answer which you can then mark as solution

Comment: ah ok., so this is a comment thats why. Ok thank you all for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this not working is, that you set the last `$('.delmod').click` eventhandler *before* the html is rendered by the browser - so it's ignored.
To make this work you'd need to put the javascript after the html.

*BUT* you shouldn't have this script inside the loop, printed several times. Move it to *after* the loop.